# How to get spark.executor.memory size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, executor

I am using Spark  2.3.2.3.1.0.0-78.
I tried to use

```
spark_session.sparkContext._conf.get('spark.executor.memory')
```

but I only received `None`.

How can I get `spark.executor.memory`'s value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you received `None`, it means that you're using the default value of `1g` (see the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties)). Only if you specifically give `spark.executor.memory` a value in your `spark-submit` or `pyspark` command you will be able to retrieve a non-null value.

So you can still programatically say that if the output of your `._conf.get()` is `None`, your executor has 1G of memory.

**Demonstration:**

Starting up a `pyspark` shell without any special configuration in your command line:

```bash
pyspark
```

And then executing the command to get the config's value gives you an empty value:

```
>>> sc._conf.get("spark.executor.memory")
```

Starting up a `pyspark` shell with a different value for `spark.executor.memory`:

```bash
pyspark --conf spark.executor.memory=2g
```

And then executing that command does return a value:

```
>>> sc._conf.get("spark.executor.memory")
'2g'
```

Comment: tks @Koedlt. Is there any API that returns a numerical value with the unit in KB? My purpose is to collect a series of pagings from an RDBMS and compare it with JVM_HEAP_MEMORY. Do you find this approach acceptable? I believe it could help alleviate the issue of small files on HDFS

Comment: I don't think it is possible  to return the units in KB if you did set the config in GB. It returns the runtime configuration property for the given key. Do a conversion instead.

Comment: @KennethChirchir In fact, that's not a very big issue. I'm facing difficulties in calculating the size of the DataFrame. It seems there's no straightforward way to accomplish it

Comment: @Sonnh , as per the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-tuning:~:text=The%20best%20way,each%20executor%20heap.), the best way to get the size of your dataframe will be be caching it and have a look at 'storage' on spark web  UI

Comment: @KennethChirchir :(( Estimate is not available in Spark 2.3.2.3.1.0.0

Comment: @Sonnh, Estimate function returns the size of java objects. What I meant is caching your dataframe to memory, then view the storage used on UI.  SizeEstimator estimate returns the java objects estimates,

Comment: oh tks @KennethChirchir, Checking the UI again doesn't meet my needs. I need to calculate and compare it with spark.executor.memory. "Lastly, automating the task is desirable."